# change background color through onkeyup of input text box

Tags: javascript

```
<input id='ad' onkeyup='sc(id)'/>
<script lang="javascript">
function sc(i)
{
    i.style.backgroundColor="#006400";
}
</script>
```

This is the code I am using to change the background colour of the input box through id, but it is not working. Please suggest some way to change the background colour of the input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `i` is an element id, use `getElementById()`

```
<input id='ad' onkeyup='sc(id)'/>
<script lang="javascript">
function sc(i)
{
    // Retrieve the element by its id 'i'
    document.getElementById(i).style.backgroundColor="#006400";
}
</script>
```